# How to render an embeded markdown snippet?

Tags: gitlab, code-snippets

I like the fact that I can easily see a rendered markdown with the gitlab snippets. However, when I embed them, it only displays the source, and does not render the markdown:

```html
<script src="https://gitlab.com/Boiethios/test/snippets/1880398.js"></script>
```

How can I embed this as rendered? Is that a know issue?

Comment: There is no mention about what you mention on https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/snippets.html, therefore I would assume that feature does not exist.

Comment: @djuarez Well, I'll just create an issue, then.

Comment: There is already an issue about this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/46851